# Do some ajax and return a promise using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson, promise

I was using this code to get data from facebook api and to be shown using Durandal, and it is working fine.

```
   return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?',
        dataType: 'json',
    }).promise();
```

I was trying to do the same using getJSON

```
$.getJSON( "http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?");
```

I tried the following code; it didn't work.

```
 var jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?");
 return jqxhr;
```

This gets me the data from the facebook.

But the issue is in returning the promise. Since I'm using durandal it is important to return a promise for the module to work.

How to return a promise while we use `getJSON`?

**This my durandal module**

```
define(function (require) {
    return {
        getCustomers: function () {
            //do some ajax and return a promise
            var jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?");
            return jqxhr;
        }
    };
});
```

**This is where I call it**

```
define(function (require) {
    var backend = require('backend');
    var ko = require('knockout');

    return {
        customers: ko.observableArray([]),
        activate: function () {
            var that = this;
            return backend.getCustomers().then(function (result) {
                var arr = [];
                arr.push(result)
                that.customers(arr);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has done the trick. Thank you guys

```
return $.getJSON( "http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?").done();
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
$.getJSON( "http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?").promise();
```

Comment: it's already with promise interface : _"This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR," returned by $.getJSON() implements the Promise interface"_

Comment: @RoyiNamir So how to implement this 'return a promise' thing?

Comment: True. all of the functions are already present on the original `jqXHR`. Calling `.promise()` just gets the promise with only the promise interface functions, leaving behind the other `jqXHR` stuff.

Comment: @PaulDraper: yeah I just want to return the promise part

Comment: I suppose that will have some (minor) memory advantages if you use a whole bunch of these.

Comment: @PaulDraper: I have added the whole module code for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

it's already with promise interface : *"This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR," returned by $.getJSON() implements the Promise interface"*

Look here  at the example :

```
var a=$.getJSON( "http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?");

a.done(function (){...}).fail(function (){...}).always(function (){...});;
```

ps

> "This gets me the data from the facebook."

NO. this returns jqXHR object.